# Name litteral object with parent name

Tags: javascript, api, dom, google-chrome

I'm working with the Google Chrome API and I'd like to name a litteral object with the parent's name  of a node (`var tree[0].parentName = {};`)

I'm currently searching for the good syntax but if anyone knows -- can they give it to me please?

Thanks,

Bruno

Comment: DOM elements don't have names per-se (although some tags such as `input` can have an attribute `name`). Could you elaborate on your requirements?

Comment: So, if I'm exploring the bookmarks' tree how can I have the name of the folder's in the bookmarks ?

Comment: Ah beg your pardon, I didn't realize you were referring to bookmarks. Nodes in this tree may have a name, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use eval(); in this case.

Something like this should do the trick (implying the parentName is "aParent") :

```
eval('var ' + tree[0].parentName + ' = {};');
//A new variable named tree[0].parentName ("aParent" in this example) was created
alert(aParent);
```

Hope this helps!